# Error: Could not find or load main class with Spark in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, scala, apache-spark

Facing issue while running a spark application from Eclipse (scala). However I'm able to run Scala from eclipse without any issue; the issue seems to appearing only with spark app.

> Error: Could not find or load main class com.sidSparkScala.RatingsCounter*

```
package com.sundogsoftware.spark

import org.apache.spark._
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.log4j._

/** 
  * Count up how many of each star rating exists in the MovieLens 
  * 100K data set.
  */
object RatingsCounter {

  /** Our main function where the action happens */
  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    // Set the log level to only print errors
    Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.ERROR)

    // Create a SparkContext using every core of the local machine, named RatingsCounter
    val sc = new SparkContext("local[*]", "RatingsCounter")

    // Load up each line of the ratings data into an RDD
    val lines = sc.textFile("../ml-100k/u.data")

    // Convert each line to a string, split it out by tabs, and extract the third field.
    // (The file format is userID, movieID, rating, timestamp)
    val ratings = lines.map(x => x.toString().split("\t")(2))

    // Count up how many times each value (rating) occurs
    val results = ratings.countByValue()

    // Sort the resulting map of (rating, count) tuples
    val sortedResults = results.toSeq.sortBy(_._1)

    // Print each result on its own line.
    sortedResults.foreach(println)

  }

}
```

Comment: Have you added scala nature to your project in eclipse ide???

Comment: Sorry for the naive question, but is the `package` statement actually missing or did you just forget to paste it here?

Comment: Have you given the proper package name. i guess there is some mismatch in the package name.

Comment: Actually there is a mismatch in the package name. It worked well once i gave the correct name. Not sure how i overlooked such a small thing and spent whole day to figure out the issue :). Great catch. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like the package name you originally created is this `com.sidSparkScala.RatingsCounter` and the package name mentioned in the script is `com.sundogsoftware.spark` (at the top). All you have to do is replace the package `com.sundogsoftware.spark` with `com.sidSparkScala.RatingsCounter`.

Answer (score 0):

Your class is not compiled properly, otherwise eclipse could find this class. Please check, is there any compilation error.

Answer (score 0):

You must change the package name to yours, not the courses provided. 
I guess you **import** this scala file from **external**, based the code above, the package is **com.sundogsoftware.spark** , just change it to yours would be fine.